# How to create a cronjob to update all nodes

Tags: 7, cron, entities

I have a content type that has a computed field that needs to be updated constantly. 
So I need to create a cronjob to update all nodes of a certain type (example 'page'), so that the code is executed from the computed field and its value updated.

thx

Answer (score 2):

- You need to create a custom module to do this.
- Implement [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to create a cron job in custom module
- You can update a node programatically.. For more details see [node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)

Comment: if I implement hook_cron, How I run the job every 2h (for example)?